# What is the norm of this bounded linear functional?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $a$, $b$ be two arbitrary but fixed real numbers such that $a < b$, let $C[a,b]$ denote the normed space of all continuous real (or complex) valued functions defined on $[a,b]$ with the maximum norm, and let $f$ be the functional defined on $C[a,b]$ as $$f(x):= \int_{a}^{b} x(t) x_0(t) dt $$ for all $x$ in $C[a,b]$, where $x_0$ is a fixed element of $C[a,b]$.

Now $f$ is evidently linear and bounded. How to compute the norm of $f$? What is this norm?

And what is the norm of the bounded linear functional $g$ defined as follows: $$g(x):= \int_{a}^{(a+b)/2} x(t) \cdot dt - \int_{(a+b)/2}^{b} x(t) \cdot dt$$ for all $x$ in $C[a,b]$?

Comment: I've answered your second question. In the future, please start a new question instead of adding or changing your question **after** you receive answers. Also, it looks like you received many excellent answers to your previous questions, please consider accepting them. See this on how: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Thanks. I've just accepted an answer. My display settings do not show some of the controls---links and buttons---on webpages. I'm afraid I need to study the Lebesgue measure and integration. In fact I have yet to start on these topics.

Answer (score 4):

Since every $x \in C[a, b]$ is continuous on a compact set, it's bounded.

For any $x \in C[a, b]$, we have:

$$
|f(x)| = \left|\int_a^b x(t) x_0(t) \, dt \right| \le \int_a^b |x(t)| \cdot |x_0(t)| \, dt \le \|x\| \int_a^b |x_0(t)| \, dt
$$

Thus, $f$ is bounded and its norm satisfies:

$$
\|f\| \le \int_a^b |x_0(t)| \, dt \newcommand{sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}
$$

In fact, equality holds. To see this, consider the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) $\hat x(t) = \sgn(x_0(t))$. By [Lusin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem), there is exists a sequence of functions $x_n \in C[a, b]$ such that $\|x_n\| \le 1$ and $x_n(t) \to \hat x(t)$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $t \in [a, b]$. By the dominated convergence theorem, we have:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b x_n(t) x_0(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_a^b \lim_{n \to \infty}  x_n(t) x_0(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_a^b \sgn(x_0(t)) x_0(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_a^b |x_0(t)| \, dt
\end{align}

---

For the second linear functional you added, approximate the following function via Lusin's theorem in a similar manner:

$$
\hat x(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t \le \frac{a+b}{2} \\
-1 & \text{if } t > \frac{a+b}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: To check equality you should take $x(t)$ which approximates the sign of $x_0(t)$...

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Ah, right. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Goodness me! This is by no means trivial. How can we justify the interchange of the limit and the integral to give the second equality? Here the convergence is not uniform, when $a < 0 < b$, for example.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Are you familiar with the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)? All of the functions $x_n(t)x_0(t)$ are dominated by the integrable function $|x_0(t)|$.

Comment: Can we infer from Lusin's theorem that $x_n(t)$ converges monotonically to $\hat{x}(t)$?

Comment: Then we can conclude that $x_n(t)x_0(t)$ is dominated by $|x_0(t)|$?